# How to use Chinese characters in libtcod?

Tags: python, encoding, fonts, chinese-locale, libtcod

I have an idea of using Chinese characters as an entities in my ASCII-like roguelike console game. I'm using python-tcod, but I don't know if there is a way to use Chinese characters in it.

I tried setting Chinese fonts through console_set_custom_font function, which worked good in displaying English characters, but not the Chinese ones. They just don't display.

```py
libtcod.console_set_custom_font('GoJuOn.TTF', libtcod.FONT_TYPE_GREYSCALE)

libtcod.console_init_root(constants['screen_width'], constants['screen_height'], constants['window_title'], False, libtcod.RENDERER_SDL2)
```

I tried to make my character look like 你， but got this. (You can see the character moving by it's FOV and how it covers items.)

[image: failure gif]

For example, that's how it worked before.

[image: success gif]

The source code is taken from libtcod python [tutorial](http://rogueliketutorials.com/tutorials/tcod/part-12/)

upd: I tried using '你'.encode() with gb18030, gbk, gb2312, hz, cp950, bi0ghkscs, big5, iso2022_jp_2 encodings, but it gave me output of wrong symbols. For example, paragraph sign or tilda ('~'), or a few letters with dots over it.

upd2: code I tried to use with another encoding

```
player = Entity(0, 0, '你'.encode('gb18030'), libtcod.white, 'Player', 
render_order=RenderOrder.ACTOR, blocks=True,
                fighter=fighter_component, inventory=inventory_component, level=level_component)
```

Code in common which renders char ('你' char is entity's char property)

```
def draw_entity(con, entity, fov_map, game_map):
if libtcod.map_is_in_fov(fov_map, entity.x, entity.y) or (entity.stairs and game_map.tiles[entity.x][entity.y].explored):
    libtcod.console_set_default_foreground(con, entity.color)
    libtcod.console_put_char(con, entity.x, entity.y, entity.char, libtcod.BKGND_NONE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Chinese character requires specific encoding.

Referring to issue reported [here](https://bitbucket.org/libtcod/libtcod/issues/123/console_print_ex-cannot-be-used-with-color). Suggest you encode the string prior to passing it to libtcod. Consider to encode the string with

`.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: I tried using gb18030, gbk, gb2312, hz, cp950, bi0ghkscs, big5, iso2022_jp_2 encodings, but it gave me output of wrong symbols. For example, paragraph sign or tilda ('~'), or a few letters with dots over it.

Comment: Can you edit the question and include the code snippet of what you have written ?

Comment: Added, check upd2 section